# How To Change Command Prompt Codepage in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, special-characters, code-page

I'm using dir command in a command prompt to export file & folders names, but I encounter problems with some Spanish characters: á é í ñ ó.

My code page is 437, how can I change it to 850?

Comment: Your question seems to be about Windows 7, not the MS-DOS operating system.  Please remove the "ms-dos" tag, and rephrase your question to refer to the "command line".

Answer (score 3):

Use the chcp command:

`Chcp [codepage]`

So you would use the following command in cmd:

`Chcp 850`

I assume you mean Command Prompt when you say MS-DOS.

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html

Comment: Great! Thanks twice, not just it worked, but the link provided indicated that the right code I was looking for was 1252 (West European Latin)!